# Extracting specific column of different files and put them together in one big file in R

Tags: r, file, scripting, paste, text-processing

I have 100 files, of which I want to extract the 4th column (total_volume) containing 100.000 rows and put it together in 1 big file which then contains 100 columns with each 100.000 rows. I was trying something with the following script:

```
setwd("/run/media/mydirectory")
library(data.table)
fileNames <- Sys.glob("*.txt.csv")
#read file in fileNames
for (fileName in fileNames) {
dataDf <- read.delim(fileName, header = FALSE) 
# remove columns with only example values 
dataDf <- dataDf[, -(7:14)] 
# convert data frame to data table 
dataDt <- data.table(dataDf)
# set column names
setnames(dataDt, c("mcs", "cell_type", "cell_number", "total_volume"))
#new file with only total volume
total_volume <- dataDt$total_volume
#export file
write.table(dataDt$total_volume, file = "total_volume20.csv")
```

But what I get then is that all columns get superimposed with as result a .csv file with the 4th column of only the last file. I would like the columns to be next to eachother instead of being superimposed. How could I do that? 
Thanks in advance!

P.S. Obviously the overwriting thing happens because I used a loop. However, I am not sure how else to combine everything, so suggestions are very welcome!

Answer (score 3):

You haven't given us a reproducible example, so I can't test this properly, but this should give you a table with one column for total volume from each of the files you get from the call to `Sys.glob()`. The idea is to make a function that does what you want for one file; use `lapply()` to make a list with the results of that function for each file in your target environment; then `cbind` the columns in that list into one big table.

```
setwd("/run/media/mydirectory")
library(data.table)
fileNames <- Sys.glob("*.txt.csv")

# For the function, I'm reproducing your code. You could do in fewer lines and without
# data.table if you like, but maybe there's a reason you chose this approach.
extractor <- function(fileName) {
    require(data.table)
    dataDf <- read.delim(fileName, header = FALSE) 
    dataDf <- dataDf[, -(7:14)] 
    dataDt <- data.table(dataDf)
    setnames(dataDt, c("mcs", "cell_type", "cell_number", "total_volume"))
    total_volume <- dataDt$total_volume
    return(total_volume)
}

total.list <- lapply(fileNames, extractor)
total.table <- Reduce(cbind, total.list)
write.table(total.table, file = "total_volume20.csv")
```

Or do that last bit in one line if you like:

```
write.table(Reduce(cbind, lapply(Sys.glob("*.txt.csv"), extractor)), file="total_volume20.csv")
```

Comment: the column removal in data.table will require "with" as dataDF[, -(1:4), with = F]. Instead of Reduce you can use data.tables' rbindlist.

Comment: Thanks. On rbindlist, though, the OP specified that he wants the results returned as columns in the final table, not rows, and I see that there's no cbindlist. Is that right?

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I meant and it works (had to omit the with=F though).

Comment: Great, and sorry about the with bit. As you can tell, I don't know data.table.

Comment: The "with" bit is required if the file is already a data.table. I see now that you read with read.delim, so it is still a data.frame there. Instead of read.delim you can use the faster fread from data.table.