# extract a column from multiple excel files and concatenate them into a single file with R

Tags: r, excel

I have about 100 excel files (with one sheet), of which I want to extract the 4th column and put them all together in one file in R (and in this new file I would like to stack all the columns into a single column of data with their headers in the second column)

How could I do that in R? Thanks in advance!

---

I found this solution here :  ([Extracting specific column of different files and put them together in one big file in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32200409/extracting-specific-column-of-different-files-and-put-them-together-in-one-big-f))

```
setwd("XXX")
fileNames <- Sys.glob("*.csv")
extractor <- function(fileName) {
  dataDf <- read.csv2(fileName, header = TRUE) 
  Column4 <- dataDf$Column4
  return(Column4)
}

total.list <- lapply(fileNames, extractor)
total.table <- Reduce(cbind, total.list)
write.table(total.table, file = "New-file.csv")
```

But I have this error message : number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2) => because of mismatch in the lengths of the vectors

How can I fix this ? Many thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

filenames <- list.files(pattern = '\\.xlsx', full.names = TRUE)

map_df(filenames, ~readxl::read_excel(.x) %>% 
          select(4) %>%
          mutate(col = names(.)[1]) %>%
          rename(value = 1)) -> result

writexl::write_xlsx(result, 'new_data.xlsx')
```